# collapsible lists in lightswitch html client with external data source

Tags: lightswitch-2013, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have been searching for some plugin/extension/code which could help me generate a collapsible list. Even though visual studio provides a plugin for the same, the developer specifies that the plugin can only be used for screens with intrinsic(created in lightswitch) data sources [LsCollapsibleList](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1af6596f-7ff3-4df4-aac9-56c60295c904)

I have also tried using the [jquery mobile](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!zThemeParams=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) theme for the same and am able to get the zip file.

The main problem is that I do not know which files to use and where to reference them.

Any help on the topic is welcome.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

have you tried following this:

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3246/Creating-Advanced-LightSwitch-HTML-Screen-Templates.aspx

this website is great for things like this, and theres also a downloadable version of the project so you can see how it all works:

http://silverlight.adefwebserver.com/Files/LightSwitch/LsCollapsibleList.zip

before referencing them, the best way is to drag the css file into the Content folder (within the visual studio environment), and the js file into the Scripts folder. This means visual studio knows the files are there within this specific project.

Finally, you would reference both the css file and the js files in the default.htm file which is located with the HTML Client structure... for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/CollapsibleLists.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Generated/CollapsibleList.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try and get back to you If the problem persists